# Unity 3D как сделать управление персом как в стратегиях(указываешь точку и он двигается)

Tags: unity3d

Насколько знаю нужен скрипт, может есть что-то в инете?

Comment: Попробуйте поискать :\

Comment: Тут не бюро по поиску скриптов для тех, кто знать не желает о программировании.

Answer (score 1):

### Используйте Raycast

Вам надо будет выпускать луч с помощью [`Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html), получать координаты и отправить вашего "перс"-а туда.